# Dynamic class based on database query in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, metaprogramming

I'd like to do something like this in Django:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     items = Items.objects.all()
     for item in items:
         # How does this part work?
         exec(item.name) = forms.BooleanField()
```

The goal is to create one form field for each item returned from the database query. So, if I get ten items back from the query, then the class would have ten variables in it, each named after a returned item.

This seems theoretically possible, but is there some danger here? The items in the database are not user generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically modify a form however you please:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         for item in Item.objects.all():
              self.fields[item.name] = forms.BooleanField()
```

I suppose the danger is if the database state changes while a user is submitting a form, and the new form initializes with new fields which the previous form didn't have.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I also found this article after I posted that really gets into the details: http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

Answer (score 0):

if I was you I would have used django formsets.

Why formsets were not an option here ?

Comment: Actually, I haven't ever used formsets. Django is huge. Hopefully, I won't need to learn another part of it just yet.